# Removing section numbering still generates numbers in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I use the report-class. To remove the section numberings, I use this in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother
```

This works as I want; sections are shows only using the names I add in `\section{Foobar}`.

However, the section numbers (and sub*section numbers) are seen in front of the names when I generate the toc with `\tableofcontents`. Chapter numbers are shown, which is what I want, but I don't want the section numbers.

**Question**: How do I get rid of the section numbers in the toc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you also want to get rid of subsection counters and so on, you could just change `secnumdepth`:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}
\duckument[toc]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]